# what is the correct path to pro lightswitch development for someone with c# winforms background

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have just started with LS and it looks like I will have to muck with Silverlight/xaml/LS extensions to go beyond what is provided out of box. My background is winforms / c#. Never done wpf, asp.net, silverlight, xaml etc.

**1) Should I learn wpf and/or XAML first or can I jump right into silverlight control development ?**

**2) Do I need to know asp.net ?**

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Should I learn wpf and/or XAML first or can I jump right into silverlight control development ?

You should know XAML, but that is included when you learn Silverlight. Don't do 'WPF first', it's another branch. When you know (a fair bit of) SL you can look at developing controls.

> 2) Do I need to know asp.net ?

A little. Not much beyond the generated host pages.

But when moving outside/beyond LightSwitch, you may want to look at WCF and DataServices.